# Electron-React ipcRenderer error "window.require is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm following a lot of tutorials about integrating react and electron using ipcRenderer, but could not find any explanation why I'm getting an error "window.require is not a function" in my App.js.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
const { ipcRenderer } = window.require('electron');
function App() {

return (
<div className="App">Rendered</div>
);

}
```

Please help.

Comment: i'm following this tutorial BTW.
[link](https://patrickpassarella.com/blog/creating-electron-react-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a 3 year old tutorial is not a reliable source, I recommend you take a look to [Electron docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/) instead.

In the tutorial, `webPreferences.nodeIntegration` is set to `true`, which is not recommended for [security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content) reasons. You should not call directly `electron` in your renderer process (i.e. your React code).

If you want to use [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc) to communicate between your main and renderer processes, you can use a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) script to expose what you need ([but never IPC functions directly](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation#security-considerations)). If I take the example from the tutorial, here is the secure way to do it:

**Preload**

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI', {
  getData: (params) => ipcRenderer.send(channels.GET_DATA, params)
});
```

**Renderer**

```
const { electronAPI } = window;

const getData = () => {
  electronAPI.getData({ product });
};
```

And if you expect a response from the main process, you most probably want to use [`invoke`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args)/[`handle`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainhandlechannel-listener), and not [`send`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrenderersendchannel-args)/[`on`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main#ipcmainonchannel-listener) with a `useEffect`. [Here is an example.](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc#pattern-2-renderer-to-main-two-way)

Comment: you don't know how much you help me, cheers.

Comment: Excelente respuesta!